# CakePHP inserting data to database doesn't save

Tags: php, cakephp

I am practising cakephp now but my inputs can't be saved to my database. Here is my code to function add:

```
public function add(){
        $this->layout = 'default';
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Applicant->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your account has been saved.');
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add account!.');
        }

    }
```

I need help.

Comment: Are your sure on that add action is execute after press sumbit button?

Comment: Can you print `$this->request->data` ?

Comment: add you applications/add.ctp code.